# NHibernate Save, Delete, Save yields unique key violation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a scenario where I need to do the following in a transaction:
1. Save a model with a unique key
2. Delete that model
3. Save a *new* model with the same unique key the first one had.

I'd expect this to work just fine, but I get a unique key violation.

NH Profiler also shows that the delete statement is not issued before the second insert.

My mapping looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHTest">
  <class name="UniqueKeyModel" table="UniqueKeyModels">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo"/>
    </id>

    <property name="TheVal" unique-key="valuniqueness" type="System.String"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My model:

```
public class UniqueKeyModel
{
   public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
   public virtual string TheVal { get; set; }
}
```

My Testcase:

```
ISession sess = ...;

UniqueKeyModel mFirst = new UniqueKeyModel { TheVal = "value" };
sess.Save(mFirst);
sess.Delete(mFirst);

UniqueKeyModel mSecond = new UniqueKeyModel { TheVal = "value" };
sess.Save(mSecond);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should flush the session after the delete. Changes are written to the database when you flush a session. <s>(If you are using transactions you have to start a new one after flushing the session)</s>

Comment: Thanks. A Flush() after Delete() apparently solves this issue.

I neglected to state that I was using transactions. e.g. using (ISess ...) using (ITansaction t = sess.BeginTransaction() ...).

The session.flush does not appear close the transaction, as I can rollback the entire transaction after a .Flush.

Comment: Thank you for your tip (in our application we are closing the transaction with the flush) - I've corrected my answer...